# Как в таймере добавлять 0, когда меньше 10

Tags: javascript

Надо чтобы когда цифра заходит меньше 10 цифра, то чтобы цифра была бы не 1, а нужно 01 чтобы было. Моя реализация

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function timer() {
    let minute = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML;
    let second = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML;
    let end = false;

    if (second > 0) {
      second--;
      if (second < 10) {
        '0' + second;
      }
    } else {
      second = 60;

      if (minute > 0) {
        minute--;
        if (minute < 10) {
          '0' + minute
        }
      } else {
        end = true;
      }
    }

    if (end) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      alert("Время истекло!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = minute;
      document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = second;
    }
  }
  window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'>
  <div id='minute'>01</div>:
  <div id='second'>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно присваиваете значение минутам и секундам когда хотите прибавить 0, точнее вообще его не присваиваете.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function timer() {
    let minute = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML;
    let second = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML;
    let end = false;

    if (second > 0) {
      second--;
      if (second < 10) {
        second = '0' + second;
      }
    } else {
      second = 60;

      if (minute > 0) {
        minute--;
        if (minute < 10) {
          minute = '0' + minute;
        }
      } else {
        end = true;
      }
    }

    if (end) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      alert("Время истекло!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = minute;
      document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = second;
    }
  }
  window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'>
  <div id='minute'>01</div>:
  <div id='second'>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function timer() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById("minute");
    var seconds = document.getElementById("second");
    var s = parseInt(seconds.innerHTML);
    var m = parseInt(minutes.innerHTML);
    s--;
    if (s == 0 && m != 0) {
      s = 60;
      m--;
    }else if(m == 0 && s == 0){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    alert("Время вышло");
    }
    minutes.innerHTML = m.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    seconds.innerHTML = s.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  }

  window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'>
  <div id='minute'>01</div>:
  <div id='second'>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно `second = 60;` заменить на `second = 59;`.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте сниппет кода с вашим решением (для этого посмотрите, например, другие ответы). Поясните коротко преимущества вашего решения.